# Javascript array to JSON array

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js

I am using JSON to send Ajax data. I am getting comma separated mobile number from the input text box.And, I am converting it into javascript array.
Below is my code:

```
  var myarray = {};
    myarray = this.model.get('mobileno').split(',');
```

> Result  : myarray : ["123", "4567"];

I am going to set the same value to my model like below:

```
this.model.set('mobileno',JSON.stringify(myarray ));
```

Then, the value becomes like below:

```
console.log(this.model.get('mobileno'));
```

> Result : mobileno : "["123","4567"]"

So, my model become  `this.model.toJSON();`

> Result :Object {mobileno: "["123","4567"]}

Till here, everything is correct. after that I need to set this model to another model and doing `stringfy` will give me like Below:

```
 anotherModel.set('data', this.model);
```

> "data":{"mobileno":"[\"123\",\"456\"]"}

But, I need like  "data":{"mobileno":["123","456"]}

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you convert the array back to JSON?

Comment: in my textbox i am having comma separated mobile number like 9845098450,9845098451 etc.. when i get this from model i will get like "9845098450","9845098451" like this. i need to make request like {data:{mobileno:["9845098450","9845098451"]}} so how could i achive this,

Comment: So? Why do you need JSON for that?

Comment: JSON arrays are not strings. They are actually JavaScript arrays. That was an design goal of JSON. So, if  you need a string of a JavaScript/JSON array, wait until you've finished building the array before you stringify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` makes a string from your array. That is obviously not what you want. Or it is what you want in this.model as you said

> Till here everything is correct.

but in the other model, you want to set the array not as a string, but as the array. As I don't know what you are doing with your backbone.js I write it as pure javascript

```
data = JSON.parse(this.model.get("mobileno"))
```

should do the job. But you can just set

```
data = { "mobileno": myarray }
```

BTW. if the backbone.js does nothing more than confusing the javascript object and array notation, I would recommend not to use it at all. As you told us the backbone.js `this.model.get('mobileno')` returns an object containing the `mobileno` field. In my world of logic `anything.get('XY')` should return the value of `XY` not an object containing the `XY` property.

Comment: I did like this. Its working. but what is the problem with the my code?

Comment: There is no problem with your code but with the way you look on javascript objects, strings and JSON. Actually JSON is just the 'Java Script Object Notation', thus a `JSON.stringify(ARG)` just returns a string, whose contents can be  copied into javascript text to write down the status of the object. So if you say `obj=JSON.stringify(obj)` the `obj` will be a string, regardless of what `obj` was before. If `obj` was a string it will be a string, that contains a quoted string.